# How to know if a used laptop can be bought and work for extra 2 years?

Tags: mac, macbook, macbook-pro

I have to buy one of two used Macbook laptops.

The first one is a macbook pro 2010:

> Apple Macbook Pro 2010 15.4 "
>
> Processor: Intel Core i7
>
> Storage: 500 GB
>
> Graphics: Intel HD Graphics
>
> Memory: 8 GB
>
> Resolution: 1440 x 900

For 700$.

The second is Macbook Pro 2017:

[image]

The second is priced for 600$.

My Question is that when I test the both Macs, how could I know the best one and even if it used, how could I know that it will last for at least couple of years with me.

Comment: Is your data correct? There's absolutely no contest between those two at those prices. 7 years newer & also cheaper - those retail at about €2500

Comment: That's why I am asking here. I don't know why he is asking for just 600$

Comment: Google "fell off the back of a lorry" ;)

Comment: It could be that yeah :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Inspect the outside of the Notebooks. See if there are any problems with the hinges, the trackpad, the keyboard, the back and the bottom

Then, the heat development. Let a benchmark test run and see how hot it gets.

The software is not to worry about as much. If you know how to clean a drive and how to reinstall the OS, you won't have many problems there.

Comment: how to do the benchmark test ?

Comment: Just download some benchmark software. https://novabench.com/ for example. Here's an article I've found about this: http://www.pcworld.com/article/258473/how_to_benchmark_your_pc_for_free.html